# Failed CSS using Django

Tags: html, css, django

I am a beginner and i recently tried to experiment in Django.
I was following a tutorial in designing a Django blog but i encountered a problem when I tried to integrate my css.
I have tried other various methods even outside the tutorial but I have still been unable to connect the two files.
I have tried some of the suggested methods from other posts but they did not resolve the issue

html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Ugandan Engineers
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/posts.css' %}">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class= "page-header">
            <div class= "container">
                <h1><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">Engineers</a></h1>
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu">
                    {% include './icons/file-earmark-plus.svg' %}
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

css file

```
h1 {
    color: darkblue;
}

h2 {
    color: blueviolet;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    color: brown;
}

.page-header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px; 
}
```

the css is supposed to center align the text as well as change the color of my h2 and h1 elements

both base.css and posts.css have identical code.
I tried using the method in the tutorial the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/posts.css' %}">`
and when that failed i used tried the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">`
It also didn't work
I tried them separatley that is why the second one is a comment.

After that i checked and made sure they was no cache, the correct file was the one i had opened, the css worked, the html was good. and it just didn't work in django.

i run these two independently outside of django and it worked.
I checked the views, urls, models and they are all fine.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

are set in settings

Comment: Did you set STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_URL in settings file?

Comment: Have you run collectstatic? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: @ Edward Moffet I have

Comment: When you open mentioned static file url manually do you see the css file contents or do you get 404 or whatever error?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the STATIC_ROOT, check [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/). Your setting should look like this:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

After making any changes look in your console for an error when trying to load the css, like `GET 'static/css/posts.css' 404`

Comment: I have tried it an I have got the error message anyways around it?

Comment: @Whiteharks, I rewrote my answer; but there's not much more to it. Check well your settings.py file. If you're still getting the 404 would you please share your folder structure and the error text